# Why emptying contents of a div loosing the css style

Tags: jquery

I was trying to create the code as present under the follwoing Fiddle dynamically

http://jsfiddle.net/7j61bxbv/3/

**I approached it the follwoing way**

http://jsfiddle.net/7j61bxbv/5/

```
var id = "275" ;

$("#result").find("#"+id).html("");


var html = '<h3>Test <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon"></a></h3><ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL">';

  html += '<li class="labellist">\
        <div class="leftlable">\n\
        <h4> Ruchulu</h4>\n\
        <p>Area Name,  <b>Phone:</b> +91 99890 11223</p>\n\
        <p><b>Timings:</b> 11am - 2pm</p>\n\
        <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 250/-  Delivery Charges Free</p>\n\
        <label class="label-red label-wrap">Close</label>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div class="rightlable">\n\
        <a href="#">Remove</a>\n\
        </div>\n\
        </li>';

html += '<div class="label-BtnWrap"><button class="icon-plus btn btn-c">Add More</button></div></ul>';

$("#result").find("#"+id).append(html);
```

When i run the above program the end result is that the Collapsable style is lost on the header , please let me know how to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct your problem you are not using the correct jquery mobile css classes. If you add the appropriate class name in your h3 tag you will get the css style

```
var html = '<h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit ui-icon-minus">Test <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon"></a></h3><ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL">;
```

Comment: But it was working  properly  with static html know without this h3 tag . But even i replaced this h3 tag data its not being expanded or collapsed .